# Doesn't Visual Studio 2015 Community edition support live code analyzer?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, static-code-analysis, roslyn-code-analysis

I have a Visual Studio 2015 professional (in Windows 7) and Visual Studio 2015 community (in Windows 10), both of have latest update 1 installed. And I have both of them opened the exactly same solution. Both tools also have `Refactoring Essentials for Visual Studio` plug-in installed.

In professional edition I can clearly see live code analyzer actually works:
[image]
You can see the wave lines under files, folders, projects and solution. When I hover mouse over then I can preview the issue before I compile the code.

However in community edition, no such thing happens at all:
[image]

Does Microsoft do this deliberately to limit the feature of community edition? Last time I heard Roslyn should be equally supported in community edition.

Comment: Try PVS-Studio. This tool support Community Editions. Example of use: "New Year PVS-Studio 6.00 Release: Scanning Roslyn" - http://www.viva64.com/en/pvs-studio-download/

Answer (score 1):

From what I learned, Roslyn code analyzers should work in VS 2015 Community Edition. However, highlighting errors in the whole Solution Explorer is handled by a **different extension** than you have mentioned - it is Productivity Power Tools 2015.